# Oracle: Use of Materialized view for avoiding Socket Read Timeout;

Tags: sql, oracle, view

We have a spring application. We generally have to execute several SQL queries on the view exposed to us by the Client.
In one scenario our queries work fine but the count(*) over the same queries creates problems. It returns 
    `org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException - StatementCallback;`

```
IO Error: Socket read timed out; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out]
```

We asked the client to increase the `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` property.

He instead has offered to expose a materialized view.

Can a materialized view helps in situations like these (where count queries lead to timeouts.)

How Materialized views can ve leveraged upon to increase performance of Queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A materialized view is a great solution to your problem. Materialized views store the results of queries in a table, and can significantly improve performance. Your client seems to be doing you a huge favor, as they will be responsible for maintaining the objects that support the query.

The only potential downside depends on how they implement the materialized view. If they create a fast-refresh materialized view, it will automatically store the correct result after every change to the data. But there are many limitations to fast-refresh materialized views, and most likely your client will provide a complete refresh materialized view, which must have a schedule. If they provide a complete refresh materialized view, make sure the application can work with old data.

(Or course, the database timeout settings may still be inappropriate. There could be a bad profile, a bad sqlnet.ora parameter, a bad setting for resource manager, an ORA-600 bug, etc. You might want to find out the specific reason why your query timed out. Not that I think the client is trying to hide things from you; a terrible DBA would have just said, "tough luck, fix your stupid query". The fact that you're being offered a materialized view is a good sign that they are really trying to solve the problem.)